# How to nest a field under another using register_rest_field in WP REST API

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

**I found that I can´t achieve this. See SOLUTION section at the bottom**.

I am using function `register_rest_field` to publish some custom meta fields in Wordpress REST API.

The API response looks something like this:

```
id: 1
meta: []
my_custom_field: "some value"
my_another_custom_field:
    0: "Alfa"
    1: "Bravo"
    2: "Charlie"
```

**What I want to accomplish is to nest my custom fields under the meta field.** So it will result in something like this:

```
id: 1
meta:
    my_custom_field: "some value"
    my_another_custom_field:
        0: "Alfa"
        1: "Bravo"
        2: "Charlie"
```

I have tried using `register_meta` function instead. It does help with nesting under the `meta` field. But it support only scalar values, and I need to display array values too (as in the example field my_another_custom_field). So I have to stick on the register_rest_field function.

**Is there a way to nest custom fields under the meta field with the register_rest_field function?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now know it is not possible. You can either expose fields with array type (with `register_rest_field` function) OR you can expose your fields under the `meta`  attribute (with `register_meta` function), that can´t be of the array type. But not both.